# How to create and assign a string to clipboard so that when pasted MS Word will accept it as a table?

Tags: c#, ms-word, clipboard

I have to find a way to generate a string so that when set and then pasted to a Word document it will display a table.

I did some research about this, but none of them seem to work. One of the things I tried was to generate a string of HTML, then set it as the clipboard data and pass format as HTML.

```
string html = @"<html><body><table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  </table></body></html>";

Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, html);
```

but it did not work, nothing was pasted to word doc when I tried. And then when I set Data format as text (DataFormats.Text) it was pasted but only as text, not as a table.

Comment: Have you tried using `Clipboard.SetText` instead of `Clipboard.SetData`?

Comment: @Dai yes, just pastes the text

Comment: ...with `TextDataFormats.Html` ?

Comment: @dai yes just tried. It pastes nothing.. And when i checked it by pressing windows+V , it shows an empty clipboard

Comment: Did you look into what word itself places in the clipboard when you copy a table?

Comment: @TaW : when i set the format as html clipboard is empty. But obviously when u manually copy a table from a word file the clipboard shows the text content of the copied table

Comment: I just did the test: Word places a table in rtf format which you can easily put into a richtextbox..: `var data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
            richTextBox1.Rtf = data;` - The other way around should work just as well, you only need to learn the rtf table format..

Comment: I've been doing some research into using HTML text with `Clipboard` and apparently there's some speciifc data and headers you need to add to a HTML string for it to be pasteable, e.g. `Format:HTML Format` and `StartFragment`.

Comment: @TaW Oh? RTF tables aren't anywhere near as expressive as HTML tables though - and Word definitely supports pasting HTML tables without using RTF as an intermediate format - I just don't know (yet) how to make it work argh.

Comment: @TaW : That seems like a great lead. Thanks

Comment: Do note that my example was quick and dirty; the Rtf in a Rtb ought to be manipulated with some more care; But: you really want to go the other way round anyway.

Comment: @Dai : Is it possible for you to add the documentation which u found? Im willing to learn the specifics tags required. Thanks

Comment: @Dai: Anything Word can do can be exported as rtf, afaik

Comment: @TaW _"Anything Word can do can be exported as rtf, afaik"_ - that's untrue, sorry: I am (unfortunately) too familiar with Office's OOXML formats and there's a reason [the OOXML spec for `*.docx` is **an absolute unit**](https://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/154.html) [while the RTF spec is a few dozen pages long and last updated in 1999](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec.html).

Comment: @kas https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format

Comment: Yeah, well you are probably quite right. But otoh, the post is a bout a (probably) rather simple table.  - By doing a  `var formats = Clipboard.GetDataObject()GetFormats();` one can see that word places an impressive number of formats into the clipboard. And by grabbing the html one can see that it look painfully complicated, or, at least long. But that is also true about what word places there as rtf. But: creating a valid rtf table  is one path I know I would at least try..

Comment: @TaW : have u tried doing the reverse of what u did. ? So, i set the resulted rtf string to clipboard using c#. But when i tried to paste in word again only the plain rtf code was pasted, just like it happened with html.

Comment: Did you set the correct format when filling the Clipboard: Example : `data = data.Replace("11111111", "JJJJJJ");  // make a change
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, data);` Works here when using the orginal data and changing them a little.. - For specs see [here](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading40)

Comment: Minimal example: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0");

for (int r = 0; r < rr; r++)
{
    sb.Append(@"\trowd");
    sb.Append(@"\cellx1000");
    sb.Append(@"\cellx2000");
    sb.Append(@"\cellx3000");
    for (int c = 0; c < cc; c++)
    {
        string ccc = dataGridView1[c, r].Value.ToString();
        sb.Append(@"\intbl " + ccc + @"\cell");
    }
    sb.Append(@"\row");
}
sb.Append(@"}");
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, sb.ToString());`

Comment: cellx has the left cell position..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, **everything** you need to know is in Microsoft's own article on this very topic: how to use Win32's Clipboard API to copy and paste HTML:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format

(Note: at the time of writing, there's a small irony in that an article about correctly formatting HTML for the clipboard itself is itself a mesh of Markdown and broken HTML... so I thought I'd *act all civic* for once and fix the broken HTML and... I ended up basically rewriting the article, [here's the PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/1325#issuecomment-1236169438)).

---

To pass HTML through Windows' Clipboard API, you need to do a few things:

- The entire HTML text must be structurally valid HTML (so you *can* still hang on to any Netscape-era HTML when everyone WAS SHOUTING ALL THE TIME BECAUSE HTML TAGS WERE ALL UPPERCASE and few bothered to ever use a `</p>` or `</li>`).

  - ...but you *can't* do things like `<script><head></p>`.
  - While HTML like `<span><div></div></span>` is syntactically valid and well-formed, HTML itself doesn't allow `<span>` to parent a `<div>` and requires browsers to break-up the outer `<span>` into separate siblings and cousins and bring the single `<div>` to the top-level - and the documentation doesn't mention what happens if you attempt to copy (or paste) "HTML" like that - though I *assume* Windows doens't care and just treats it as a big string, but the possibility of *having fun* with other applications that consume pasted HTML (e.g. Word, Excel, etc) because this is how security vulnerabilities start.
  - Also, it's also completeley undocumented how Windows and other applications handle HTML's Custom Elements feature.
- Then you need to generate a header, with the right parameters, and the right formatting *just for it to work*. Computers are awful.
- As you're passing in a single large element (the `<table>`, I assume?) then the `<table>`'s `outerHTML` can be the bounds of the actual HTML fragment that will (or rather, *should*) be copied by the receiving application.

  - This outer element, the fragment, is marked with HTML comments `<!--StartFragment-->` and `<!--EndFragment-->`.
- Only *now* can you calculate the values of those header parameters (which
  *also* represent an intentionally redundant representation of the `<!--Start/EndFragment-->` bounds)...

  - ... the problem is the insertion of those `Start/EndFragment` comments into the HTML makes the message longer would break any previously calculated absolute offsets.

So, <sub>(Doug DeMuro voice)</sub> ***this*** is the template for text data representing a HTML fragment being placed into the Windows Clipboard:

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:AAAA
EndHTML:BBBB
StartFragment:CCCC
EndFragment:DDDD
[StartSelection:CCCC
EndSelection:CCCC]
<HTML goes here>
```

- The headers are separated by simple line-breaks. Curiously MS's documentation says that all 3 major line-break-styles were permissable (`\r`, `\r\n`, and `\n`),
- The last 2 headers/parameters (`StartSelection` and `EndSelection`) are optional (*but* such that you must either supply neither or supply both - supplying only one of the two `Start/EndSelection` parameter will break things in unspecified ways.

  - My personal favoute is [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).
- Now do this:

  1. Copy that template into a new `String` and stick your completed HTML directly at the end of the header, separated by a single line-break.
  2. Take a look at that header above. See at the top where it says `Version:1.0`? Yeah? Good. Ignore it.
  3. Now see th `StartHTML` parameter below. We will calculate that last. Ignore it for now
  4. Next is `EndHTML`, which is the absolute byte offset (from the start of the header, not the HTML) of the *end* of the HTML text itself - basically it's the *message length*.
  5. `StartFragment` is the absolute byte offset (from the start of the header) to the `<` in a well-formed HTML element representing the fragment itself.

  - The inserted `<!--Start/EndFragment-->` comments must be considered **outside** the fragment (i.e. a `String` representation of your fragment's raw HTML would not have those comments in it anywhere)..

  1. `EndFragment` is the absolute byte offset (from the start of the header) to the end of the fragment. This is an exclusive upper-bound (so if `StartFragment=100` and `EndFragment=150` then the fragment is 50 char in length, simple).

     - **Important note:** Remember the text run represented by `Start/EndFragment` must be a valid kinda-"self-contained" element. So you cannot have a fragment that abrubtly ends *inside* a tag or its attributes - nor start half-way through a container element's many text nodes...
     - ...*however* the `Start/EndSelection` headers, if present, *can* start and end at arbitrary points in the human-readable text (but conversely, the documentation does not say what happens if `Start/EndSelection` are inside an element's tags or attributes, for example).
- Then substitute those calculated numbers into those `BBBB`/`CCCC`/etc placeholders below: but **do not delete unused placeholders**: instead replace them with a leading digit `'0'` character.

  - Don't worry: in this case (at least) any leading zeroes are *not* interpreted as forcing octal (base-8) integer parsing, *phew*.

1. Oh, *almost forgot*: go back to the top to caclulate `StartHTML`, which is the absaolute byte offset to the start of the HTML text (and of the opening `'<'` in `<htm>` I assume).

So you'll end up with this:

```
string htmlInTheClipboardLooksLikeThis =
@"Version:1.0
StartHTML:0081
EndHTML:0263
StartFragment:0016
EndFragment:0126
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><table>
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Savings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
</table><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>";
```

and you just need to pass it into `SetText` (*not* `SetData`) with `TextDataFormat.Html`:

```
Clipboard.SetText( htmlInTheClipboardLooksLikeThis, TextDataFormat.Html );
```

and just running that in Linqpad gives us something we can paste directly into Word... and it indeed imported it as a Word table:

[image]